# Null metatamodel fields with inherited @Embedded

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, metamodel

I am experiencing NPEs with some embedded JPA metamodel fields using Hibernate 4.3.5.Final.

Specifically, I have the following situation:

1. `@Entity` class `A`
2. `@Embedded` class `B` in class `A`
3. `@Embedded` class `C` extending class `B`

I am *not* getting the 'Unable to locate static metamodel field...' error on startup which seems common in these situations, however all of `C_`'s fields are null.

Pertinent chunks of my code, simplified for legibility are:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "...")
public class A extends AbstractA {

    // Attempting to define override in superclass
    @AttributeOverride(name = "cField", column = @Column(name = "SOME_FIELD"))
    @Embedded
    private B b;
    ...
}


@Embeddable
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class B extends C {

  @Column(name="SOMETHING")
  private String bField;
  ...
}


@Embeddable
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public abstract class C implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String cField;
    ...
}
```

In this example, `C_.cField` is null.

The corresponding generated metamodel classes for the embedded classes are:

```
@Generated(value = "org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor")
@StaticMetamodel(B.class)
public abstract class B_ extends C_ {
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<B, String> bField;
}

@Generated(value = "org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor")
@StaticMetamodel(B.class)
public abstract class C_ {

    // This object is null
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<C, String> cField; 
}
```

Unless I've just mucked something up, a key question which I haven't seen answered is - can an embeddable class extend another embeddable class? I've got it working using association rather than inheritance - namely, having `C` as an an `@Embedded` field in `B` - but I'd prefer inheritance if possible.